# Add new column to DataFrame based on information from another DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hey I have two `DataFrames`: `data1` with columns `KEY`, `value1`, `value2`, and `data2` with column `KEY`(but we can assume that there is much more columns). Now I want to create `value` column in `data1` in such a way that if a given `key` is in `KEY` column in `data2`, then `value` is equal to `value2`, and else it is equal to `value1`. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {"KEY": ["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"], "value1": ["ABC",[] , []], "value2": ["abc", "XYZ",[] ]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 =  {"KEY": ["KEY2"]}
data2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

data1["value"] = data1.apply(lambda x: x["value2"] if x["KEY"] in list(data2["KEY"]) else x["value1"], axis = 1)
```

It works properly but I would like to know if it is the most efficient method or I can do that better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will be more efficient because there is no going over each row one by one using apply.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {"KEY": ["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"], "value1": ["ABC",[] , []], "value2": ["abc", "XYZ",[] ]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 =  {"KEY": ["KEY2"]}
data2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

index_1 = data1.set_index("KEY").index
index_2 = data2.set_index("KEY").index
intersection = index_1.isin(index_2)

data1.loc[intersection, "value"] = data1.loc[intersection, "value2"]
data1.loc[~intersection, "value"] = data1.loc[~intersection, "value1"]
```

And output:

[image]